# Android external library reference and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to test out this api: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/ in Android. I created a new app and copied the library and dependencies from the prev url to the project's "libs" directory then added references to them through Java Build Path->Libraries->Add jars...

Here's the test Activity:

```
package com.jimmcgowen.googleapispelling;

import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker;
import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellCorrection;
import org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellResponse;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path") );
    }

    public void onDoIt(View view) {
        EditText input = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.PlainText );
        String word = input.getText().toString().trim();

        SpellChecker checker = new SpellChecker();
        SpellResponse spellResponse = checker.check( word );

        for (SpellCorrection sc : spellResponse.getCorrections()) {
            Log.i("Spell Checker", sc.getValue());

            TextView tv = new TextView( this );
            tv.setText( sc.getValue() );

            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.ResultContainer );
            container.addView( tv );
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles fine but when I run it I get:

```
07-22 16:16:48.673: E/dalvikvm(29209): Could not find class 'org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker', referenced from method com.jimmcgowen.googleapispelling.MainActivity.onDoIt
07-22 16:16:48.703: W/dalvikvm(29209): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 28 (Lorg/xeustechnologies/googleapi/spelling/SpellChecker;) in Lcom/jimmcgowen/googleapispelling/MainActivity;
07-22 16:16:48.713: D/dalvikvm(29209): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0015
07-22 16:16:48.713: D/dalvikvm(29209): VFY: dead code 0x0017-004c in Lcom/jimmcgowen/googleapispelling/MainActivity;.onDoIt (Landroid/view/View;)V
07-22 16:16:48.903: I/classpath(29209): .
07-22 16:16:48.903: D/ATRecorder(29209): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@40529128
07-22 16:16:53.948: D/AndroidRuntime(29209): Shutting down VM
07-22 16:16:53.958: W/dalvikvm(29209): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2192)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9299)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4352)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2187)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    ... 11 more
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.xeustechnologies.googleapi.spelling.SpellChecker
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    at com.jimmcgowen.googleapispelling.MainActivity.onDoIt(MainActivity.java:29)
07-22 16:16:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29209):    ... 14 more
```

Notice that classpath is empty at runtime. I think this is where the problem lies but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Using API level 8
SDK tools 20
Platform tools 13
and I just updated the eclipe plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jars to the asset folder and then link them to the project build path. Dont forget to select the jars in the order and export tab.